# Celery task unable to find time.sleep()

Tags: django, import, celery

I have a strange issue with celery tasks. The task itself is a simple test task that calls sleep in a loop thus:

```
@shared_task()
def testtask(num=100):
    for i in range(num):
        import time
        print_log("in testtask {0}".format(i))
        time.sleep(1)
    return
```

Calling testtask(x) from the python IDE works just fine. I have imported all the relevant celery app stuff before this.

Calling testtask.delay(x) causes the task to get queued, but fails with the following error:

```
[2023-05-15 16:36:39,168: ERROR/ForkPoolWorker-2] Task profiles.views.testtask[8beca657-e492-4526-9aac-ddba42eae653] raised unexpected: NameError("name 'sleep' is not defined",)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/raxak/raxak/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 450, in trace_task
    R = retval = fun(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/raxak/raxak/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 731, in __protected_call__
    return self.run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/u01/rp/raxak/profiles/views.py", line 1498, in testtask
    print_log("in testtask {0}".format(i))
NameError: name 'sleep' is not defined
```

Error comes no matter where I put the `import time` line: at the start of the file, in the loop, just after the def testtask etc. Also strange that the error is flagged as being on the print_log line which is before the one that is invoking sleep. Must me something so obvious that I am missing it somehow. It does not matter if I import time and do time.sleep(1), or if I do from time import sleep and do sleep(1). The error is not on the import time line, it is where sleep is used.

### Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Aaargh. Pilot error. Workers need to be manually restarted after any changes to the code. Failed to do that. It is actually working fine. Sorry.

Comment: Good job :) I advise to simply delete Question, as it's not of any help whatsoever.

Comment: @NixonSparrow, It's definitely helpful. I'm new to using Celery and didn't know I needed to restart workers after changing the code... until I read Prasanna's answer.